# Is there a way to run kotlin script in adb shell like a shell script?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Is there a way to run kotlin script in adb shell like a shell script? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin is no script language so the short answer: This is impossible.
There is a experimental plugin to compile Kotlin to JavaScript, but this won't ether work in the adb shell. There you can just execute commands, no scripts. Except you root your device but this is no average case.

Comment: Kotlin can be ran as a scripting language, just not on android: [Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) `Kotlin can also be used as a scripting language. A script is a Kotlin source file (.kts) with top level executable code.`